# HttpSenRequest POST ==> GET?

Tags: web-services, winapi

I have connections to two (unrelated) webservices; both are accessed using POST requests passing a JSON string.

using this logic:

```
Create a session (InternetOpen)
Connect to server on given port (InternetConnect) (either secured or not)
Create a request on the connection, POST a script (HttpOpenRequest)
In a loop:
 Look for options (InternetQueryOptions) to set flags;
 Set options when instructed
until this os Ok.
Once Ok: in a loop
 Send request (HtpRequest) sending the JSON string.
 Get last error.
 Set security if requested, handle other errors.
until send Ok of some error has occured in processing.
If sending was Ok, get the return data (InternetReadFile)
```

One site fails in `HttpSendRequest`, stepping through the code with a sniffer running in parallel, I see:

> POST the request, returns status 200
>
> GET (I guess status) returning status 400: with this error tekst.

and it looks as if the data is not accepted by the service.

However, `GetLastError` returns 0.

The sniffer shows the following output on executing ONLY the `HttOpenRequest` call: (data obscured, but all valid)

> POST  HTTP/1.1
>   Content-Type: application/json
>   User-Agent: (MyConnector)
>   Host:(Remote host:port)
>   Content-Length: 21604
>   Pragma:no-cache
>   
>   { (JSON string) }
>   
>   
>   
>   HTTP/1.1 301 MOVED PERMANENTLY
>   Date: Tue, 09 Sep 2014 15:38:31 GMT
>   Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
>   Expires: Tue, 09 Sep 2014 15:38:31 GMT
>   Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0
>   Last-Modified: Tue, 09 Sep 2014 15:38:31 GMT
>   Location: 
>   Vary:
>   Accept-Encoding
>   Content-Length: 0
>   Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

> GET  HTTP/1.1
>   User-Agent: MyConnector
>   Host: :(Remote host:port)
>   Pragma: no-cache Connection: Keep-Alive
>   
>   
>   
>   HTTP/1.1 400 BAD REQUEST
>   Date: Tue, 09 Sep 2014 15:38:31 GMT
>   Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
>   Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0
>   Vary: Cookie,Accept-Encoding
>   Expires: Tue, 09 Sep 2014 15:38:31 GMT
>   Last-Modified: Tue, 09 Sep 2014 15:38:31 GMT
>   Content-Length: 34
>   Connection: close
>   Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
>   
>   Only http POST method is accepted.

and `GetLastError` was not yet called.

Is this 'normal' behaviour, and if so, is there a way to suppress this GET? It *may* cause the service to abort processing of incoming data.

The weird thing is it has worked; the database of the service contains data that can only be entered using this interface!

As far as it is relevant: The application is developed using Delphi 2007 on a Windows XP professional system, originally tested and working on Windows 8 Professional 64-bit, where it all worked fine. No changes in the code on either sides (Mine hasn't, the other side tells me they didn't change a thing either. The webservice is a Python application).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to RFC 2616:

> 10.3.2 301 Moved Permanently
>   ...
>   Note: When automatically redirecting a POST request after receiving a 301 status code, some existing HTTP/1.0 user agents will **erroneously** change it into a GET request.

If that is what WinInet is actually doing, then it is doing the wrong thing.  It should not be changing the request type during a 301 redirection.  Hard to say for sure without seeing your actual code, not pseudocode.

Comment: This is indeed what happened, I guess. The server has returned this code, and that triggered a deeper research on the code. Turned out the string containing the script to execute didn't end in "/" and the server issued a redirect (301) to the exact string PLUS that "/", instead of handling it internally.... Adding "/" to the string solved the problem.